# crash in security framework with call SecItemCopyMatching

Tags: ios, iphone, security, monkey

we have a bug run in `monkey`, the call back stack like this:

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b853224 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b85309c mach_msg + 72
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b744ee4 _dispatch_mach_send_and_wait_for_reply + 540
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b7452e8 dispatch_mach_send_with_result_and_wait_for_reply + 56
4   libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018b96cee0 xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply_sync + 196
5   Security                        0x000000018cc8fe44 securityd_message_with_reply_sync + 200
6   Security                        0x000000018cc90114 securityd_send_sync_and_do + 80
7   Security                        0x000000018ccb5c88 __SecItemCopyMatching_block_invoke_2 + 212
8   Security                        0x000000018ccb7730 __SecItemAuthDoQuery_block_invoke + 304
9   Security                        0x000000018ccb478c SecItemAuthDo + 1116
10  Security                        0x000000018ccb5424 SecItemAuthDoQuery + 492
11  Security                        0x000000018ccb5ba8 __SecItemCopyMatching_block_invoke + 116
12  Security                        0x000000018ccb3c3c SecOSStatusWith + 52
13  Security                        0x000000018ccb5aec SecItemCopyMatching + 396
```

I want obtain `bundleSeedID` and my code:

```
NSDictionary *query = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       (__bridge NSString *)kSecClassGenericPassword, (__bridge NSString *)kSecClass,
                       @"bundleSeedID", kSecAttrAccount,
                       @"", kSecAttrService,
                       (id)kCFBooleanTrue, kSecReturnAttributes,
                       nil];
CFDictionaryRef result = nil;
OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)query, (CFTypeRef *)&result);
```

this code is copy from net, I don't know what's wrong, need you help!